# DOM Parser giving error on img tag

Tags: javascript, html, domparser

Hi i am trying to parse img using DOM PARSER and it throws parse error for some reason.
please help me find the solution. As far as i know image tag doesn't need closing tag and browser removes it on load which is creating the parsing issue.

[image]

**Fiddle:**

**http://jsfiddle.net/ygR4L/**

**HTML:**

```
<body>
    <img src="test">
</body>
```

or

```
<body>
    <img src="test"/>
</body>
```

or

```
<body>
    <img src="test"></img>
</body>
```

**javascript:**

```
var html = document.body.innerHTML;
function parseXML(html)
{
    var parser, componentDoc;
    if (window.DOMParser)
    {
        parser = new DOMParser(); // should work for FF and IE 9
        componentDoc = parser.parseFromString(html,"application/xhtml+xml");//this line must be creating the issue. which mime type is better 
    }
    else
    {
        componentDoc = windowsParse(html);
    }
    return componentDoc;
} 

var component = parseXML(html);
console.log(component);
```

Comment: `<img src='test'></img>` is not valid, use `<img src='test' />` _format_.

Comment: even that doesn't work...

Comment: please check the fiddle

Comment: You probably need the something like `<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>` before your `html` tag to parse `application/xhtml+xml`.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

An image tag, after being handled by the DOM parser, is internally treated as:

```
<img src="test">
```

Notice that it is not self-closing (that doesn't exist in HTML), nor does it have a closing tag (because `<img>` does not have `</img>`).

(To demonstrate this, try `console.log(html);`)

As such, the HTML you are trying to parse is... well, just an opening tag. But you're telling it to parse as XHTML+XML, which does not have this rule on `<img>` tags.

You could potentially use `text/html` as the type of document, however keep in mind that this will generate a bare-bones `<html><head></head><body><img></body></html>` structure.